# VSCode & ESLint - Not displaying errors but giving ESLint errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, eslintrc

I have a `.eslintrc.js` configuration file in my workspace; when I break a rule enforced by ESLint, my React application gives the errors and it works as expected.

[image]

What I'd like to see is the linting in VSCode telling me what is wrong however, there are none.

[image]

I've used it previously where it tells you what is wrong and gives options to resolve, even if it's an `// eslint-disable-next-line no-console` for example.

I've been through workspace/user settings and compared with my old machine and they all appear to be the same (with thanks to settings sync) but recently, it's stopped working on my old machine (I guess, with thanks to settings sync).

Am I missing something simple?

In the ESLint console, there are some complaints that it can't find the config file

[image]